# How does Apple know which passwords never to be saved?

Tags: macos, ios, password, keychain

When you input a new username/password combination, Apple (macOS and iOS alike) asks if you want to save the password, also offering responses of “never” and “not now.”

I understand the “save” response: the password is encrypted and stored in the keychain, and if iCloud is turned on, it syncs across devices.

I understand the “not now” response: make the decision another time.

What I don’t understand is the “never” response: The password, seemingly, has to be saved *somewhere* that the system can access it and, if it’s set to never, not prompt a “save password” dialogue after inputting it. Try a different username/password on the same website - you’ll see that it cues the dialog again, thus proving that it doesn’t save a list of websites.

Is this accurate? Does Apple actually save passwords you told it not to save, and “never” really amounts to “don’t ask me again”?

The same question may be asked for credit cards on supported OS’s.

Comment: Why do you think they would save the credit card info during 'never' response?  I always thought they kept a record of the site you were on and used that to suppress the dialog in the future.

Comment: @fab Try inputting a new user/pass combo on the same site - you’ll see that it will cue the dialog again. Editing to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It saves the site for which you don't want to save the password, not the password itself.
You can see the sites at:
Safari->Preferences->Passwords

Comment: Again, I can punch in a new username and password and it’ll ask me if I want to save that. If the entire site is blocked, why should that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different @Dogberry, and thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @DonielF I tried to reproduce your observations using macOS Safari 11.0 but couldn’t. As soon as I click “Never”, this choice is recorded in the Preferences dialog, just as the answer says. From that point on, Safari never shows a prompt again for that particular site, no matter which username I try. This is the site I have tried: https://www.heise.de/security/dienste/browsercheck/demos/demo-login.html

Comment: Doniel: that isn't what I observed. I tried it at latimes.com, a site I haven't created a user before. I created a user, which logged me in. When I clicked Logout, that is when Safari offered to save. I said "Never." I then created a 2nd account. When I clicked Logout, Safari didn't offer to save it. Not sure why you are seeing another prompt a second time. You sure it is Safari asking, and not some password manager? 1Password offers to remember it when I create the account. I have to tell it no every time, but that manager is designed to remember passwords.